# 同じ文字列の場合は必ず同じ配列の値となるよう、文字内容に応じて配列の値を割り振りたい

Tags: php

**やりたいこと**

- (数が無限にある)任意の文字列に対して、必ず配列内の何れかの値を割り振りたい
- (後で実行する場合でも)同じ文字列の場合は、必ず同じ色(配列の値)となるようにしたい

  $hoge = ['赤','青','黄','緑','黒','白','橙','茶'];

どういう方法がありますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

細かい要件がわかりませんが、そのような用途なら`hash`が使えるかもしれません。

```
<?php
    $inputString = "テスト用文字列";
    $hoge = ['赤','青','黄','緑','黒','白','橙','茶'];

    //ハッシュ値を求める。今回の用途なら暗号学的に強力なアルゴリズムを使用する必要はない。
    $hashValue = hash('md5', $inputString); //$hashValue = md5($inputString); としても同じ
    //配列のインデックスに使うため整数値に変換
    $hashInt = intval(substr($hashValue, 0, 8), 16);
    //色配列から色を求める
    $color = $hoge[$hashInt % count($hoge)];
    echo $hashValue.':'.$hashInt.':'.$color;
```

出力例(エンコーディングがUTF-8の場合):

```
9a15fb2809c058e6842ff1f727bc610b:2585131816:赤
```

入力文字列をバイト列としてハッシュ値を求めるので、結果はエンコーディングに依存しますが、同一エンコーディングならどんな環境で何回実行しても必ず同じ結果になるはずです。

Comment: 期待通り動作したのですが、「intval($hashValue)」ではなく「intval(substr($hashValue, 0, 8), 16)」としている理由は整数値変換以外に何か意図がありますか？　基数指定して速度向上している？　あるいは、より出力される値を均等にしている ？？

Comment: 記数を指定しないと`intval`は文字列を10進数として解釈しようとします。`hash`関数の戻り値は、出力例でおわかりのように16進数の文字列なので、速度云々は関係なしに基数の`16`は指定してやる必要があります。`substr`で先頭8桁を切り出しているのは32bit分を取り出しています。phpの整数型は実行環境依存で32bitの場合と64bitの場合があるので、結果が実行環境に依存しないよう32bit分(4bit×8)を取り出しています。

Comment: 10進数以外に対してintval使用する際は、基数指定が必要なのですね。また、先頭8桁については実行環境(32bit，64bit)を考慮した結果なのですね。全く思いつきませんでした…

Answer (score 0):

典型的 [ハッシュ関数](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%8F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A5%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0) ですね。

- ある任意の入力があるとき（この例では文字列）
- なんらかの変換関数によって有限個の数値を得る（この例では `[0, 8)` の整数）

変換関数の性質として

- 同じ入力に対しては同じ値が得られる
- 出力される値はどれもほぼ均等になる

のが望ましいとされています。

文字列を何らかの方法で数値 `value` に変換し `value%個数` でも立派なハッシュ関数です（性能が良いかどうかは別問題として）

Comment: 「ハッシュ関数」を初めて知りました。今回の目的にピッタリだと思いました